# How google is crawl my database without connecting?

Tags: search-engine, google-search

I have website and added the google custom site search. It works fine and displays the results. The pages are stored in the database and allowed to edit by Administrator (as CMS solution)... How google search the content and displays from my database content? I would like to know the technique or method google follow?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does not have access to your database, only your web pages. It regularly crawls your web pages and indexes them, just like it would for its own search results. The only difference is it serves up results specific to your website to your website.